# Considerations when declaring a GUID Object

Tags: c#, .net

A while back I wrote a small one-page web application which accepted just a few inputs from the user. It turns out that the data it collected over a two week period was all bad, due to an oversight in how I wrote the code. I can't remember exactly 'how' i declared my string, so hence my question now as I would like to avoid this mistake in another project I am looking at now.

Scenario:
In my page, I have a couple of methods which all reference a GUID I created when the page was initialized. I need this GUID to remain the same right up until the user clicks 'Submit'. I can't use a HiddenField as I have trouble interacting with this when using the Ajax file upload, and I do not want to use a Session, in case the user opens multiple Tabs with the same page. This leaves me with declaring a GUID in the code behind. How do i declare this GUID so that it is only for the user who created it?

The issue I had with my previous program is that *'somehow'* i declared a string or an int (i can't remember which one it was) and it didn't matter if 10 people were submitting the form at once, they would all take on the value of whoever set it last. this meant that my data was absolute garbage.

```
public partial class _FormInputs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static Guid MyGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Would the above allow only the user submitting the form to reference 'their' instance of this GUID?

```
public partial class _FormInputs : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static Guid MyGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Would the above allow any users of the web application to access 'MyGUID', and obtain the value of what it was last set at (regardless of who set it)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is this GUID used for? Only when they press Submit in the end? In that case, show us what you do with it in the function handling the submit request. It sounds like you could just generate the GUID there - no need to store it in the HMTL page.

Comment: If you are trying to store it per request, like a CSRF token, better to map it against a requestid or for user session, use the MVC's ClaimsIdentity -> UserId claim and store it so that you can identify the user's process.